# 80s or 90s movie/serial, Chinese men, special agents, face shifting masks

Tags: story-identification, movie

Please help me finding this movie or serial (80s or 90s). There were some special agents (white and Chinese or some Asian looking) involved in it. (Not sure they were all agents though).

The white agents were collaborating with some Chinese men and some of them were their enemies. The main trick was that those Chinese men would pull over their head some thin masks, which completely covered up their face and even their whole head so that facial features and hairs would look absolutely different. Those masks were so great that no one could tell if the person was wearing any mask or that person just looked this way naturally.

I'm not quite sure about some advanced technology as I watched it back in 90s. But it seems like those masks were just so thin and very professionally made so that they could reshape one's face into another person's.

The Chinese bad guys would wear those masks to become a different  Chinese-looking person or even like a white person so that the white agents could never tell the difference who that person really was when talking to them face to face.

In the final scene some white guy was negotiating with a man in a friendly manner thinking he was his friend. Then suddenly that person revealed his real face by pulling off his mask and he happened to be his worst enemy. So the good guy was shocked that he couldn't have detected the mask on that man before. (There was also some shooting involved at that moment, but not sure.)

It's not *Mission Impossible*, though the masks there are made the same  as in this movie.

Comment: Was there magic involved in those masks? Advanced technology?

Comment: The Mission Impossible series had these kind of mask reveals https://i.imgur.com/i4NLvvu.gif

Comment: The mission impossible masks are made this precise way the masks I saw in my series. But it was definitely other series as I know Mission Impossible

Answer (score 3):

Die Another Day.

Some things from beginning - James Bond infiltrates a North Korean military base runned by Colonel Tan-Sun Moon then his deputy Zao had contact with an unknown source who reveals Bond's true identity. Bond in this movie wear a mask to blend in.

Later he discover that Graves british millionaire rat him in DPRK and he was source of blown cover. Graves was making deals with North Korean officials.

Then Bond infiltrates Graves command centre and he met Graves and Zao. Bond discovers that Graves is in fact Colonel Moon, who has used the gene therapy technology to change his appearance.